# comparing rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Requirement - compare two rows , if found duplicate row ,display popup of "duplicate rows" and wouldn't proceed to next cell.. this code is not working as it is comparing column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long
 If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G:L")) Is Nothing Then
   If Target.Value <> "" Then
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(j, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value And j <> Target.Row Then
                MsgBox "row having same value"
                Target.Clear: Target.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
   End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop. You can use the excel function `CountIf`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("G:L")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Target.Column), Target.Value) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "Row Having Same Value"
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.ClearContents: Target.Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @Yasserkhalil please check my requirement , i have to compare two rows if value in the rows are same than show popup of duplicate rows.

Comment: i have to compare two entire rows